# What is the replacement of `babel-plugin-module-resolver` for babel v7?

Tags: babeljs

After upgrading to babel v7, the plugin `babel-plugin-module-resolver` doesn't work.

Is there any replacement for this plugin?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does it error? It feels like that's the actual question.

Comment: sorry, I should make it more clear. It turns out that it is a undocumented change causing some trouble, as stated in my own anser.

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question.

It turns out that babel v7 + babel-plugin-module-resolver v3 combination has some change that doesn't support alias starting with $.

My original config is as below

```
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "$src": "./src"
        }
      }
    ],
```

The leading `$` is our alias convention that works for a long time. After the upgrade, the `$src` is not recognized any more.